# Where to put exception handler for form level exception

Tags: .net, wpf, forms, exception

For long time I was indicating errors in my programs by returning values. Recently I switched to throwing exceptions which seems to make code cleaner and therefore more goal-oriented.

I'm able to set-up exception handlers

- on application level (there are many resources around on this topic)
- on ad-hoc basis where needed

But I can't figure out if an exception handler can be set up at **form level**.
Expected behavior:

- If **FormA.Button_Click()** throws an exception, it it caught in handler for **FormA**
- If **FormB.Button_Click()** throws an exception, it is caught in handler for **FormB**

The goal is to avoid putting individual `try/catch` into many event handlers (but many contain non-trivial actions so they need handling). But I still wish to stay in the context of the form, keeping current form open and active after error message is displayed (for example in **MsgBox()**).

Where is the form's main event loop located so I can put exception handler in there? Is this approach correct?

*(Platform of interest:  **WPF + VB.NET**, but I also understand **WinForms** and speak **C#**)*

Comment: Don't put business logic in your events and route all events to a controller so you can handle all exceptions in there.

Comment: @Amorphis - please consider converting this comment into an answer so it can eventually get accepted, if no one gives more helpful one. Also, your suggestion shifts problem of exception handling to controller level (if I don't want to write individual try/catch statements. Is a command wrapper containig exception handler a good approach in such a case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are the bottom level calls and there is no Visible code calling them so you will have to reroute the calls to a central point of your application.

Your suggestion for a command wrapper is a good suggestion. 
You can also look at Aspect oriented programming where you can add code before the event is being fired (and also after ....) .

Answer (score 2):

Both WinForms and WPF offer an "unhandled exception" event, which you can subscribe to and report unhandled exceptions. See Application.DispatcherUnhandledException (WPF) and Application.ThreadException (Forms).

However, IMHO it is better for each original UI event handler to catch and deal with the exception. By the time the event is raised, you don't have as much useful context for dealing with the exception, and your program may or may not still be in a coherent state (depending on the exception).

For exceptions you can safely handle, those need to be handled in the context of the operation that understands how and why they can be safely handled. For other exceptions, you probably don't want your program continuing to execute…at most, you'll want to log and/or report the error to the user, and then shut down the program as cleanly as can be accomplished at that point.

Note that this may involve routing to a controller, per Amorphis's reply. But the actual catching and initial handling of the exception should still reside in the UI event handler that initiated the operation that ultimately resulted in the exception.